# 64 bit integers in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

How do I deal with 64 bit integers in QML? I know that useless Javascript can't handle them normally as it uses doubles for everything, and if I try to use them in a signal, everything gets set to `undefined`. Is there a way around this? Perhaps I have to use a `QVariant` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own `Integer64` class derived from `QObject` and give it the functions you need, like

```
class Integer64 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ...
    Q_PROPERTY(QString value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
    QString value() const;
    void setValue(QString value);

    Q_INVOKABLE void add(Integer64 * other);
    Q_INVOKABLE void subtract(Integer64 * other);
    Q_INVOKABLE void multiply(Integer64 * other);
    Q_INVOKABLE void divide(Integer64 * other);
    // ...
```

where you use value() to get a string representation in QML and setValue() to set a value from a string representation.

An additional constructor can be used to efficiently create `Integer64` from C++

```
public:
    explicit Integer64(QObject *parent = 0);
    explicit Integer64(qint64 value, QObject *parent);
    // ...
```

Then register the type to QML

```
qmlRegisterType<Integer64>("MyModules", 1, 0, "Integer64");
```

Comment: Integer64 is QObject derived, yet you have Integer64 being passed by value in the functions.

Comment: QObject's are non-copiable by design. Trying to pass one by value is a compile time error. Since it cannot be copied, the same limitation applies to all sublclasses.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to fix this? I just found "Note that all C++ types registered with the QML type system must be QObject-derived, even if they are non-instantiable."

Comment: Just use pointers, references to QML objects are received as pointers on the C++ side.

Comment: Also, when you "return" a object to QML, it is also returned as a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not need methods on your 64-bit object, use `Q_GADGET` to create a type that you can store in a QVariant:

```
struct Int64Data
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    int64_t value;
};
```

Register using:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Int64Data>();
```

You can pass this type to QML:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getMax() {
    Int64Data idx;
    idx.value = INT64_MAX;
    return QVariant::fromValue(idx);
}
```

You cannot manipulate it directly in QML, but you can pass to slots:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void dumpIndex(const QVariant idx) const {
    if (idx.canConvert<Int64Data>()) {
        auto data = qvariant_cast<Int64Data>(idx);
        qDebug() << "Index value:" << data.value;
    }
}
```