# How to register types like QList<quint64> in QJSEngine?

Tags: qt, qt5, qjsengine

I use scripting in my Qt-app with the QJSEngine. One of my C++ functions returns `QList<quint64>` type, and I need to call it from javascript. It's called with no errors. However, it returns `QVariant(QList<qulonglong>)` instead of expected list of integers. Another function which is defined to return `QList<int>` in C++ works fine from javascript, returning the list of integers. I've looked through the docs of `QJSEngine` and `QJSValue`, and found no hints for solving this issue. P.S. the `quint64` itself works also fine - it's just the list of them which does not work.

Comment: JS doesn't support U64: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/does-javascript-support-64-bit-integers   You didn't mention QML but you could create your own class like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781083/64-bit-integers-in-qml  What is going on there (most likely) is that Qt is converting the U64 to variant list since there is no native JS type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use QVariantList instead. QVariant supports qlonglong and qulonglong which are the same as qint64 and quint64.

```
QList<qlonglong> list;
```

or convert:

```
QVariant v(list);
QVariantList vlist = v.toList();
```

Comment: That's what Qt is already doing for him (wrapping the list in a QVariant ). The point is there is no native conversion of any 64b integers in JS/ECMA, signed or not. (There are new" [`Int64/UInt64`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/UInt64) types but are really byte arrays or so, and Qt doesn't support those), So there's no built-in Qt helper class to convert those types of arrays to JS objects. AFAIK there's no way to add custom containers except via dedicated classes (QObjects/Gadgets with value accessor methods, eg. like `QQmlListProperty`).